# How do I make an SQL query return false when trying to insert a non unique value into a unique column?

Tags: php, mysql

so my problem is that I have a column that's "unique" in my database for one of the columns, assigned using PHPMyAdmin. When I try and insert something into the column that is not unique, it doesn't add it, however I want it to return "false" or something similar so that I can tell the user of the site that they can't have that username. I've already tried this code to see if it returned anything and it didn't work:

```
    $test123 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO User (UserName, Password) VALUES('$uname', '$pswd')");
    echo $test123;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539067/finding-out-why-a-mysqli-insert-failed-which-unique-index-was-duplicated

Comment: The code you've written should work. Is it really echoing `1`?

Comment: To see the value of a boolean variable, it's best to use `var_dump()` rather than `echo`.

Comment: @Barmar No, but that's what I want it to do. Thanks, your solution worked.

Comment: Why would you want it to do that? It's supposed to return `false` when the query fails because of the duplicate. When you echo `false`, it prints an empty string; when you echo `true`, it prints `1`.

Comment: I didn't know that, sorry.